# PC randomly crashes

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash

Computer crashes every 2-3 hours of normal use, on being idle and sometimes when doing something in some applications (ex. Choosing a map in BeamNG.drive).

It gives out `DRIVER_IQRL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` and `Problem source: iaStorA.sys`
The getting information progress stays on 0% and only hard reset helps to start it again.

I tried checking for updates of drivers through the Device Manager and GeForce Experience and after installing the cumulative update and graphic drivers, the BSOD is weirdly downscaled

Comment: Do you have a RAID disk?

Comment: No, I don't have a raid disk

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk(s) and also do `chkdsk` to check if this is caused by hardware. Also check the Event Viewer for interesting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update BIOS, Chipset and Intel Rapid Storage driver (that is your message), then all remaining drivers, restart and test .